# How to set IsEnabled false to all buttons of radiobutton

Tags: c#, silverlight, radio-button, silverlight-5.0, isenabled

I am c# developer and i am trying programatically to set all the radiobutton to false.

**How to set all the radiobutton to IsEnabled= false ?**

EDIT:Please note that i have kind of situation where i have to keep this  radio.IsEnabled = false; outside the loop only so is there any way that i still can have all button IsEnable= false ?

Comment: As an alternative, note that you can use a GroupBox or a Panel to hold all the RadioButtons, and then set the GroupBox or Panel's IsEnabled property, and it will automatically set it for all the subcontrols (i.e. all the RadioButtons).

Comment: @MatthewWatson you are very near to what i want. Could u please explain me in detailm somethign abouyt groupBox ?

Comment: @MatthewWatson actually i do ISEnable like this: element.FindName("param_" + enableElement).GetType().GetProperty("IsEnabled").SetValue(element.FindName("param_" + enableElement), isEnabled, null);  (TO EXPLAIN YOU A BIT THAT WHAT I AM TRYING TO DO.)

Comment: @MatthewWatson please see th edit of the code to know the exact situattion

Comment: I'm not familiar with Silverlight, so I'm not totally sure that it would work the same way, but what I'm talking about is this: With Windows Forms you can create a GroupBox or a Panel container control as a parent of a set of subcontrols such as RadioButtons, and then the Groupbox/Panel's IsEnabled property acts as a master switch for all the subcontrols. This lets you turn all the subcontrols on and off just by using the container control's IsEnabled.

Answer (score 1):

Thats because you put the `radio.IsEnabled = false;` outside of the loop.

```
{
    radio = new RadioButton()
    {
        Content = item,
        GroupName = "MyRadioButtonGroup",
       // Name = "param_"+param.Name
    };
    radio.Checked += (o, e) =>
    {
        txtblkShowStatus.Text = item;             
    };
    sp.Children.Add(radio);
    radio.IsEnabled = false;

    count++;                
}
```

Comment: tansk for answer but please see the edit of question

Comment: pleasee the commented part in my code i dont have to set the IsEnabled to false this way.

Comment: I don't think you know what you want. This answer is quite the answer you are looking for. Outside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

I assume putting `radio.IsEnabled = false;` inside your loop will do the trick..

**EDIT :**

I am not sure I quite understand why you want to set to false in second step however you can try:

```
foreach (Radiobutton r in sp.Childern)
{
 r.IsEnabled = false;  
}
```

Comment: tansk for answer but please see the edit of question

Answer (score 1):

try below code and take isEnable inside the block of code as shown below

```
foreach (String item in param.Component.Attributes[0].Item)
{
    radio = new RadioButton()
    {
        Content = item,
        GroupName = "MyRadioButtonGroup",
       // Name = "param_"+param.Name
    };
    radio.Checked += (o, e) =>
    {
        txtblkShowStatus.Text = item;             
    };
    sp.Children.Add(radio);
    radio.IsEnabled = false;

    count++;                
}
```

Comment: thanks of rthe answer but please see th edit of the question.

Answer (score 1):

You are using variable `radio` declared outside the function, declare it as local variable like this, and set `IsEnabled` each time you create it:

```
foreach (String item in param.Component.Attributes[0].Item)
{
     RadioButton radio = new RadioButton()
    {
        Content = item,
        GroupName = "MyRadioButtonGroup",
       // Name = "param_"+param.Name
    };
    radio.Checked += (o, e) =>
    {
        txtblkShowStatus.Text = item;             
    };
    radio.IsEnabled = false;
    sp.Children.Add(radio);
    count++;     
}
```

Comment: thanks of rthe answer but please see th edit of the question.

Comment: that `radio` variable outside the function, should have any connection with those radio buttons created inside the function?